# Modifying shared preference on run?

Tags: android, android-debug

I want to know is there any tool which allows me to change the value of shared preferences of an installed Android app?

Comment: there is no such tool

Answer (score 1):

Shared preferences are stored in flat XML file. If you can reach it, then you can edit. On standard system, this is private file though so other processes cannot mess with not own preferences.